# SVG not loading properly

Tags: html, css, image, svg, render

I am simply trying to render the svg on the page however it is not loading.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd"
    stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2">
    <g transform="matrix(.48451 0 0 .60177 -438.2 27)">
        <path fill="none" d="M906.2-44.5h55.3V0h-55.3z" />
        <clipPath id="a">
            <path d="M906.2-44.5h55.3V0h-55.3z" />
        </clipPath>
        <g clip-path="url(#a)">
            <path
                d="M928.5-.4v-5.8l6.3-3 6.3 3v5.5a33.8 33.8 0 01-12.6.3zM916-6.9A42.1 42.1 0 00927-1.6v1a33.4 33.4 0 01-12.5-5.7L916-7zm37.8.3A29.6 29.6 0 01942-1v-5.3l6.2-3 5.5 2.6zm-26-12.1l6.3 2.9v5.8l-6.3 3-6.3-3v-5.8l6.3-3zM907.4-16l6-2.7 6.3 2.9v5.8l-6.1 2.8c-2.9-2.5-5-5.4-6.2-8.8zm53.2-.3a21.4 21.4 0 01-6 8.9l-5.5-2.6v-5.8l6.3-3 5.2 2.5zm-12.3-12l6.2 3v5.8l-6.2 2.9-6.3-3v-5.8l6.3-3zm-13.5 0l6.3 3v5.8l-6.3 2.9-6.2-3v-5.8l6.2-3zm-27.5 0l6.1 3v5.8l-6.3 2.9a18.2 18.2 0 01.2-11.6zm52.2 10.4c.5-1.7.6-3 .6-4.6 0-1.7-.6-3.4-1-4.5l1.5-.7a17.1 17.1 0 01.2 10.5l-1.3-.7zm-31.8-20L934-35v5.8l-6.3 3-6.3-3V-35l6.3-3zm-13.8.2l5.8 2.7v5.8l-6.3 3-5.9-2.8a22 22 0 016.4-8.7zm40.4.3c2.8 2.5 5 5.4 6.2 8.7l-5.1 2.4-6.3-2.9V-35l5.2-2.4zM942-43.6c4.3 1 8.2 3 11.4 5.4l-5.1 2.4-6.3-3v-4.8zm-13.4-.6a34.7 34.7 0 0112.5.4v5l-6.3 3-6.2-3v-5.4zm-1.2 1.5c-2.3.5-4.6 1.2-6.1 2-1.6.6-4 2.1-5.1 3l-1.4-.6a30.1 30.1 0 0112.6-5.7v1.3z"
                fill="#404040" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This is my SVG from my HTML, on the webpage it is loaded.
However it doesn't render to the page.

[image]

I should add I also have a width and height on the svg of 25px.

Comment: looks fine to me - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mdOqELv

Comment: Can you show us this NOT working?

Comment: Please share your page Url with us.

Comment: https://jmason-pc.pebblelearning.lan/achieve/#!/browse-achievements the url

Comment: The image is the not working part. It loads the SVG however it doesn't render or display so we can see it.

Comment: Very strange that is works in code pen and not on my site

Comment: Your site is unreachable

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have other elements on your page with `id="a"`?

Comment: My site is local which is why you can't reach it. No I don't have anything else with id of a

Comment: And if you open the (local) SVG file in a browser? (just drag it into a Browser window) The RitWickdey LiveServer VSCode plugin is known to inject itself in SVGs (where it shouldn't) The VSCode HQ-LiveServer plugin has (thus far) worked fine for me

Comment: When creating a blank page and put pasting it on there, the SVG works just fine. My guess is it's something to do with AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something on top the icon. Try with

```
svg {
width: 25px;
z-index: 200;
}
```

Comment: Good shout however no change.

Comment: Is the svg placed in a div? Have you tried giving the display property to the svg to "block" or "fixed" or position absolute?

Comment: Tried with and without a div however still nothing renders

Answer (score 0):

```
<clipPath id="b">
    <path d="M712 0h39.1v23.6H712z"/>
    </clipPath>
<g clip-path="url(#b)">
```

Id's for all components were the same. Ids need to be unique. Must have been a setting in Affinity Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I hate weird Matrix conversions.

Your SVG is a soccerball, and I presume all that mumbo jumbo is to make it look round? It is not round!

[image]

- I multiplied the `path` by 10 with: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/
- Made it a Relative path so positioning is all done with the first `M225 444`
- adjusted viewBox
- removed SVG mumbo jumbo
- added `<circle>` for reference
- Took some minutes to adjust to `scale(1.08, 1.333)` and position with `M225 444`
- re-adjusted viewBox

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 28 28" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="2">
  <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50%' fill='red'></circle>
  <g transform="matrix(.48451 0 0 .60177 -438.2 27)">
    <path fill="none" d="M906.2-44.5h55.3V0h-55.3z" />
    <clipPath id="a">
      <path d="M906.2-44.5h55.3V0h-55.3z" />
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#a)">
      <path d="M928.5-.4v-5.8l6.3-3 6.3 3v5.5a33.8 33.8 0 01-12.6.3zM916-6.9A42.1 42.1 0 00927-1.6v1a33.4 33.4 0 01-12.5-5.7L916-7zm37.8.3A29.6 29.6 0 01942-1v-5.3l6.2-3 5.5 2.6zm-26-12.1l6.3 2.9v5.8l-6.3 3-6.3-3v-5.8l6.3-3zM907.4-16l6-2.7 6.3 2.9v5.8l-6.1 2.8c-2.9-2.5-5-5.4-6.2-8.8zm53.2-.3a21.4 21.4 0 01-6 8.9l-5.5-2.6v-5.8l6.3-3 5.2 2.5zm-12.3-12l6.2 3v5.8l-6.2 2.9-6.3-3v-5.8l6.3-3zm-13.5 0l6.3 3v5.8l-6.3 2.9-6.2-3v-5.8l6.2-3zm-27.5 0l6.1 3v5.8l-6.3 2.9a18.2 18.2 0 01.2-11.6zm52.2 10.4c.5-1.7.6-3 .6-4.6 0-1.7-.6-3.4-1-4.5l1.5-.7a17.1 17.1 0 01.2 10.5l-1.3-.7zm-31.8-20L934-35v5.8l-6.3 3-6.3-3V-35l6.3-3zm-13.8.2l5.8 2.7v5.8l-6.3 3-5.9-2.8a22 22 0 016.4-8.7zm40.4.3c2.8 2.5 5 5.4 6.2 8.7l-5.1 2.4-6.3-2.9V-35l5.2-2.4zM942-43.6c4.3 1 8.2 3 11.4 5.4l-5.1 2.4-6.3-3v-4.8zm-13.4-.6a34.7 34.7 0 0112.5.4v5l-6.3 3-6.2-3v-5.4zm-1.2 1.5c-2.3.5-4.6 1.2-6.1 2-1.6.6-4 2.1-5.1 3l-1.4-.6a30.1 30.1 0 0112.6-5.7v1.3z" fill="#404040" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>


<!-- My Version: -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx='50%' cy='50%' r='50%' fill='green'></circle>
  <path transform="scale(1.08, 1.333)" fill='#404040' d='M225 444v-58l63-30l63 30v55a338 338 90 01-126 3zm-125-65a421 421 90 00110 53v10a334 334 90 01-125-57l15-7zm378 3a296 296 90 01-118 56v-53l62-30l55 26zm-260-121l63 29v58l-63 30l-63-30v-58l63-30zm-204 27l60-27l63 29v58l-61 28c-29-25-50-54-62-88zm532-3a214 214 90 01-60 89l-55-26v-58l63-30l52 25zm-123-120l62 30v58l-62 29l-63-30v-58l63-30zm-135 0l63 30v58l-63 29l-62-30v-58l62-30zm-275 0l61 30v58l-63 29a182 182 90 012-116zm522 104c5-17 6-30 6-46c0-17-6-34-10-45l15-7a171 171 90 012 105l-13-7zm-318-200l63 29v58l-63 30l-63-30v-58l63-30zm-138 2l58 27v58l-63 30l-59-28a220 220 90 0164-87zm404 3c28 25 50 54 62 87l-51 24l-63-29v-58l52-24zm-123-62c43 10 82 30 114 54l-51 24l-63-30v-48zm-134-6a347 347 90 01125 4v50l-63 30l-62-30v-54zm-12 15c-23 5-46 12-61 20c-16 6-40 21-51 30l-14-6a301 301 90 01126-57v13z' />
</svg>

<style>
  svg {
    background: pink;
    width:180px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Not quite the issues, What was occurring was that there was multiple svgs on the page with the same ID's. clippath id="a" was the same for all SVG's. So it wasn't liking the fact they all had the same Id's.By changing the ID's on the page it worked.

Comment: I do like your approach however a nice simple SVG

Comment: and no ``id``s required